# useRouter().push() refreshing the page in next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am using the node js custom server in next js. useRouter().push() worked fine in my Next Js app without custom server. Now It refreshes my app. It donot give me single page app. I am using custom node server for the first time. Am I doing node custom server wrong??? Is the issue with node js custom server.
Can anyone Help me?

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const vhost = require('vhost')
const port=process.env.PORT || 3000
const dev=process.env.NODE_ENV!=='production'
const app=next({dev})


const handle=app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(()=>{

  
    const Server=express()
    const landing=express()
    
 
    landing.get('/', (req, res) => {
        return app.render(req, res, '/main', req.query)
      })
    
      landing.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        return app.render(req, res, `/main${req.path}`, req.query)
      })
    
      landing.all('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
      })
     
        
       
        Server.use(vhost('www.lvh.me', landing))
        Server.use(vhost('lvh.me', landing))
        Server.use(vhost(`localhost`, landing))
       
      Server.listen(port,(err)=>{
        if(err) throw err
        console.log(`http://www.lvh.me:${port}`)


    })


})
```

**pages/main/index.js**

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
export default function Home(){
    const router=useRouter()
    const navigateTo=(to)=>{
        router.push(to)
    }
return <>
<button onClick={()=>navigateTo("/")}>Home</button>
<button onClick={()=>navigateTo("/contact")}> Contact</button>
</>
}
```

**_app.js**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UseRouter().push() looks for routes only in pages folder. It did'nt worked as I was routing to pages inside main folder. Now, Page render once and do not render in further routing and UseEffect only implements once.

**Working code:**

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
export default function Home(){
    const router=useRouter()
    const navigateTo=(to)=>{
        router.push(/main${to},${to}) 
    }
return <>
<button onClick={()=>navigateTo("/")}>Home</button>
<button onClick={()=>navigateTo("/contact")}> Contact</button>
</>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this code maybe be correct

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
export default function Home(){
    const router=useRouter()
    const navigateTo=(to)=>{
        router.push(`${to}`)
    }
return <>
<button onClick={()=>navigateTo("/")}>Home</button>
<button onClick={()=>navigateTo("/contact")}> Contact</button>
</>
}
```